# What does (present) Rin mouth when she sees her father and her past self at the shrine?

Tags: shelter

At around [4:15 into *Shelter*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzQ6gRAEoy0#t=4m15s), when present-Rin is witnessing her father and her past self visiting a shrine, she mouths something as her father walks past present-her. However, there is no voiceover here; the audio is just the piece "Shelter". What is she saying?

(I don't expect anybody will be able to lipread this, but maybe Robinson or someone else involved in the production has commented about it.)